# Training with MobileNetV2 for FasterRcnn in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, faster-rcnn

I have one application trained with `MobileNetV2 using FasterRcnn in Tensorflow.`

The same training data and same procedure, I trained with `MobileNetv1`, it went well with good results.

I used pretrained models from this [page](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim#pre-trained-models) for `both MobileNetV1 and MobileNetV2.`

The only issue is that I can't initialize all finetuned variables in training MobileNetV2 from pretrained model's checkpoint. Those variables are required by MobileNetV2 trained models with FasterRCNN. But they are not available in pretrained model ([all variables from checkpoint are here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n354egcueedxbjc/pretrained.txt?dl=0))

```
WARNING:root:Variable [MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_15/expand/biases] is not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_15/expand/weights] is not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_15/project/biases] is not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_16/depthwise/biases] is not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_16/expand/biases] is not available in checkpoint
```

I can't initialize only five variables, but why the result is so bad.
Could it be any other issues?